# How do we stop a recurring SQL query running in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2

We have an instance of Magento 2.4.6 which has spawned 5 to 10 instances of the query below. When we will it, it simply spawns again and again.

We cannot trace where or why this is happening so any help would be appreciated

`SELECT` e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS` status`,` at_visibility`.`value`AS`visibility`FROM`catalog_product_entity`AS`e`INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_status_default `ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id`= '97') AND`at_status_default`.`store_id`= 0 LEFT JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_status `ON (`at_status`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id `= '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id`= 1) INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_visibility `ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id `= '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id `= 0) WHERE ((`e`.`updated_at `>= '2024-01-22T10:24:06')) AND ((`e`.`updated_at`< '2024-01-27T16:25:47')) ORDER BY`e`.`updated_at `ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100`

We have tried various things from recreated db to repair.

Comment: Mysql just executes queries, does not spawn those randomly.

Comment: Yes, I know that, it is more where the execution request originates from.